# Lorentz boost in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames

In Minkowski space, Lorentz boost is provided by the vector field
$$b^{\mu} = a(x \partial_t - t \partial_x)$$
for some arbitrary constant $a$. The integral curves of this gives the trajectory of an accelerating observer. How would I now do this in a general curved spacetime? Will $b^{\mu}$ also be the velocity boost vector field in a curved spacetime, or will that be different? If it is different, then how do I figure it out?

Comment: You will not have boost generators in general spacetimes because they may not be symmetric enough to allow for their existence. Maximally symmetric spacetimes like dS and AdS are curved spacetimes which do have boosts (see http://utf.mff.cuni.cz/~podolsky/1993/LORENTZ.pdf)

Comment: @Avantgarde Do you know of any examples of spacetimes that are not maximally symmetric, but symmetric enough to have boosts?

Comment: Unfortunately no